# CSS hover on anchor tag showing i-beam cursor for a fraction of a second

Tags: html, css

I'm learning ReactJS by recreating the [ionicframework.com](https://ionicframework.com) site. But there's a small problem.

I have a set of anchor tags in the header. When I hover over them, the cursor changes to i-beam for a fraction of a second and only then, it changes to the pointer (which is intended). This is observed in both Firefox and Chrome on my machine. The site is apparently free of this glitch. I have captured my screen to illustrate what is happening. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNmEE.jpg) the GIF hosted on imgur.

I have no event listeners attached to the links. It is pure CSS with the `:hover` pseudo class.

I also made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ark__n/vt0834x9/18/), but, unfortunately, the glitch is not very apparent. Try moving your mouse back and forth quickly over the links to see.

```css
.preheader {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 20, 56, .06);
    padding: 8px 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.container {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.preheaderMenu {
    font-family: 'Eina', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    z-index: inherit;
}

.preheaderLinks {
    z-index: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .2s color;
    padding-right: 16px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #a8b0be;
    letter-spacing: .04em;
}

.preheaderLinks:hover {
    color: #3880ff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.subMenu {
    z-index: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.preheaderLinksUnderlined {
    letter-spacing: .06em;
    color: #727a87;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e8ebf1;
}

.preheaderCTA {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s background, 0.2s color;
    color: #3880ff;
    background-color: #e3efff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.preheaderCTA:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3880ff;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="preheader">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="preheaderMenu">
          <div class="subMenu">
            <a class="preheaderLinks">FRAMEWORK</a>
            <a class="preheaderLinks">PWAs</a>
          </div>
          <div class="subMenu">
            <a class="preheaderLinks preheaderLinksUnderlined"}>
              The 2018 Ionic Developer Survey is here - Take the 2018 survey
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="subMenu">
            <a class="preheaderLinks">HELP</a>
            <a href="#" class="preheaderCTA">
              LOG IN
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

What is the problem? What can I do to stop this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are applying `cursor: pointer` on the hover function.

Try applying `cursor: pointer` for the non-hover function, like this,

```css
.preheaderLinks {
  z-index: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .2s color;
  padding-right: 16px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #a8b0be;
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: And if it's there, it can be removed from `.preheaderLinks:hover`'s rule.

Answer (score 3):

Move `cursor: pointer;` from `.preheaderLinks:hover` to `.preheaderLinks`:

```css
.preheader {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 20, 56, .06);
    padding: 8px 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.container {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.preheaderMenu {
    font-family: 'Eina', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    z-index: inherit;
}

.preheaderLinks {
    z-index: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .2s color;
    padding-right: 16px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #a8b0be;
    letter-spacing: .04em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.preheaderLinks:hover {
    color: #3880ff;
}

.subMenu {
    z-index: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.preheaderLinksUnderlined {
    letter-spacing: .06em;
    color: #727a87;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e8ebf1;
}

.preheaderCTA {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s background, 0.2s color;
    color: #3880ff;
    background-color: #e3efff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.preheaderCTA:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3880ff;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="preheader">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="preheaderMenu">
          <div class="subMenu">
            <a class="preheaderLinks">FRAMEWORK</a>
            <a class="preheaderLinks">PWAs</a>
          </div>
          <div class="subMenu">
            <a class="preheaderLinks preheaderLinksUnderlined"}>
              The 2018 Ionic Developer Survey is here - Take the 2018 survey
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="subMenu">
            <a class="preheaderLinks">HELP</a>
            <a href="#" class="preheaderCTA">
              LOG IN
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

No need to wait for `:hover` to apply it.